# Are there any tools available (web tools, PC tools, iPhone tools) to send an MMS to the iPhone which contains images and text?

Tags: ios

I would like my app to be launched if the user clicks on a custom URL within an MMS, this is working for SMSs but I would like to test it using an MMS.
Does anybody know of any tools available that would enable me to create and send an MMS to the iPhone, with the MMS containing a mixture of images and the url as a clickable link from within the MMS?

(it doesn't have to be sent from on an iPhone, I'm just looking for any way at all to get an MMS onto the iPhone containing an image and a clickable url link).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried sending via email? I think all carriers have an email formatted address for their phone numbers. Here's a random Google result with quite a bit of info:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=507548

Based on the comments, it appears to work with MMS, not just SMS. There's also a few services suggested, there.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work on T-mobile though.